# How do I make "gem install" use an edited source (and not re-download the source first)

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install a gem, but it fails because of `-Werror`:

```
$ gem install -V thrift -v '0.11.0.0' 
...
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:459:18: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  rbuf_ivar_id = rb_intern("@rbuf");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

If I edit `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/thrift-0.11.0.0/ext/Makefile` and add `-Wno-error` to `CFLAGS` (or just delete `-Werror`) I can build it just fine with `make`.

But issuing `gem install` again will overwrite my changes and fail again.  I have also tried `gem install -V thrift -v '0.11.0.0' -- --with-cflags=-Wno-error` without success.

So is there a way for `gem` to not re-download the sources?  Or an alternative way of passing `-Wno-error`?

Comment: Most likely you will need to fork the repo. Alter the [extconf.rb File](https://github.com/szechyjs/thrift-gem/blob/master/ext/extconf.rb#L27) to remove the hard coded "-Werror" flag and then you can install from this repo [gem install](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install)

Comment: With bundler you can use the path option in your gemfile to install the gem from a local repository. `gem 'thrift', path: 'path/to/my/version/of/thift'`. If you're using the gem command it will look for the gemspec in the current directory.